# How do I stop a music track from looping in Libgdx

Tags: audio, libgdx, background-music

In my project I am attempting to play a music track when the screen switches to the game over screen. It starts when it is supposed to, however, the track continuously loops even when looping is set to false. I tried also using the OnCompletionListener, However I either set it up incorrectly or It just didnt work for some reason or another

This is the variable in my create method.

`music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("gameover.mp3"));`

This is the track set up in the render method

```
        music.setVolume(.2f);
        music.setLooping(false);
        music.play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be you're calling play() in the `render()` method, try calling it on the `show()` method or use a boolean to flag that you're already playing the music and don't play it again.